# Is Normalisation is important for Factor analysis

Tags: r, factor-analysis, descriptive-statistics

I have a some surveyed data and I want to do factor analysis for the same, especially exploratory factor analysis. So before that, I want to do make my data Normalisation?

My Sample data as follows

```
X1.1.a  X1.1.b X1.1.c X1.1.d X1.1.e X1.1.f X1.1.g X1.1.h X1.2.a
1        2      4      3      3      5      5      3      0      5
2        5      5      0      5      5      5      5      5      5
3        5      3      3      3      5      3      3      3      3
4        2      3      0      2      2      3      3      0      4
5        2      0      4      3      3      3      3      3      5
6        3      5      3      3      5      3      3      3      5
```

When I check the data normalisation, the skewness(-1 to 1) and kurtosis(-2 to 2) values beyond its range. So I have tried log transformation and also sqrt transformation, I will get the exactly same issue as without transformation.

I am using R for analysis the same. using the following code

```
sqrtdata<-sqrt(mydata)
lib(psych)
describe(sqrtdata)
```

so please let me know if the **doing Normalisation is important for Factor analysis** if yes please let me know how to do the transformation in R for the above data.